# Single responsibility principle with data service

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I try to refactor my code to be clean and I wonder if I go into good direction.
I use Model View Presenter pattern but I also use Service class when I want to make connection with database.

```
 protocol NewWorkoutServiceType {
        func checkNewWorkout(workoutName: String) -> Bool
        func saveNewWorkout(exercises: [ExerciseCellInNewWorkout], workoutName: String, workoutDate: String, completion: (WorkoutModelInfo) -> Void)
    }
    
    class NewWorkoutService: NewWorkoutServiceType {
        
        let newWorkoutDBHandler: SaveNewWorkoutProtocol
        let checkWorkoutDBHandler: CheckIfWorkoutExistsProtocol
        
        init(newWorkoutDBHandler: SaveNewWorkoutProtocol, checkWorkoutDBHandler: CheckIfWorkoutExistsProtocol) {
            self.newWorkoutDBHandler = newWorkoutDBHandler
            self.checkWorkoutDBHandler = checkWorkoutDBHandler
        }
        
        func checkNewWorkout(workoutName: String) -> Bool {
           return checkWorkoutDBHandler.checkIfWorkoutExists(workoutToCheck: workoutName)
        }
        
        func saveNewWorkout(exercises: [ExerciseCellInNewWorkout], workoutName: String, workoutDate: String, completion: (WorkoutModelInfo) -> Void) {
            
            let savedWorkout = newWorkoutDBHandler.saveNewWorkout(exercises: exercises, workoutName: workoutName, workoutDate: workoutDate)
            completion(savedWorkout)
        }
    }
```

It is my service class, I use protocol to make it loosely coupled. I have read about SOLID and SRP and I have decided to break my code on small pieces with one responsibility.

```
protocol SaveNewWorkoutProtocol {
    func saveNewWorkout(exercises: [ExerciseCellInNewWorkout], workoutName: String, workoutDate: String) -> WorkoutModelInfo
}

protocol CheckIfWorkoutExistsProtocol {
    func checkIfWorkoutExists(workoutToCheck: String) -> Bool
}

class CheckWorkoutDBHandler: CheckIfWorkoutExistsProtocol {
    
    func checkIfWorkoutExists(workoutToCheck: String) -> Bool {

        let workoutModel = RealmService.shared.realm.object(ofType: WorkoutModelInfo.self, forPrimaryKey: workoutToCheck)
        
        if workoutModel == nil {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}

class NewWorkoutDBHandler: SaveNewWorkoutProtocol {
    
    func saveNewWorkout(exercises: [ExerciseCellInNewWorkout], workoutName: String, workoutDate: String) -> WorkoutModelInfo {
            
            var newExerciseModel = [ExerciseModel]()

            for section in 0..<exercises.count {
                newExerciseModel.append(ExerciseModel(number: (section + 1),
                                                exercise:
                                                    exercises[section].workoutModel.exercise,
                                                exerciseSet:
                                                    Array(exercises[section].workoutModel.exerciseSet)))
            }
            
            let workoutModel = WorkoutModelInfo(workoutName: workoutName, workoutDate: workoutDate, exercises: newExerciseModel)
        
            RealmService.shared.addModified(workoutModel)
            return workoutModel
        }
}



class NewWorkoutPresenter {

    private let newWorkoutService: NewWorkoutServiceType   
    weak var newWorkoutPresenterDelegate: NewWorkoutPresenterDelegate?

  init(newWorkoutPresenterDelegate: NewWorkoutPresenterDelegate, newWorkoutService: 
  NewWorkoutServiceType) {
        self.newWorkoutPresenterDelegate = newWorkoutPresenterDelegate
        self.newWorkoutService = newWorkoutService
   }
}
```

And I think that every think okay, but later when I initialize presenter in VC it is so big and look dirty. So maybe better option is not divide my service class on smaller pieces (separated classes for checking if workout exists and saving workout).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  private lazy var presenter = NewWorkoutPresenter(newWorkoutPresenterDelegate: self, newWorkoutService: NewWorkoutService(newWorkoutDBHandler: NewWorkoutDBHandler(), checkWorkoutDBHandler: CheckWorkoutDBHandler()))
}
```

I will be greatful for your advice!

Comment: I think you have gone too far. SRP doesn't mean a class should literally do one thing; you have a class per function. A class should have a single *responsibility*. So you could have a class for storing and fetching workouts to/from a data store and a class for "running" a workout; tracking elapsed time, or whatever. It would be a mistake for the one class to do both of those things; although they are both involving workouts they are clearly very different activities.

Comment: So do you suggest to have these 2 functions (checkingIfDataExists and savingData) directly in Service, not in seperated classes? Because checking data and saving data relate to one responsibility - data handling. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, that sounds more reasonable, although I probably wouldn't have a `checkIfExists` function, I would have a `fetch` function that returns an optional - if the workout doesn't exist you get back `nil`; if it does you get back the workout.